# I deployed my project in iis 8,Folder upper case is returns 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

My Project  in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Portals\client\` directory.

I used `<a href="Default.aspx"/>` 
it is working fine,that means url is

```
www.domain.com/portals/client/default.aspx
```

i have link button that is redirecting through code behind i,e

```
 Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx",false);
```

But it is redirecting like `www.domain.com/Portals/client/default.aspx`
 then it is redirecting to

> 404 - File or directory not found.
>    in fact if i make P upper case or any of the character upper case in portAls, it is redirecting to `404 - File or directory not found.`

what is problem?

Comment: IIS, by default, is not case sensitive, so unless you've modified some configuration somehow it shouldn't be IIS itself. Do you have any modules installed such as IISRewrite?
Have you verified if the request is even hitting your app (e.g. application_beginrequest)?

Comment: `www.domain.com/portals/client/default.aspx` it will work fine if i make any letter in poRtals only ,it wil redirect  to `www.domain.com/poRtals/client/default.aspx`  but `404 - File or directory not found.`. not getting exact issue please help me out..

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem but do not believe IIS to be the cause as this isn't case sensitive *unless you have changed something yourself*. 
Do you have any modules installed such as IISRewrite? Have you verified if the request is even hitting your app (e.g. application_beginrequest)?

Comment: I dont have any rewrite module and also i given _read/write_ permission to that folder. is anything i made mistake ???

Answer (score 0):

To find the issue you need to make clear what is the difference between final url when using `<a href="Default.aspx"/>` and `Response.Redirect()`. By default, urls under IIS are not case sensitive so this should not be the reason of your problem.

To workaround, do following

1) use `<a href="Default.aspx"/>` and see where it goes, compare target url with www.domain.com/Portals/client/default.aspx

2) make sure that www.domain.com is setup for your box

3) find where exactly your app root is. The "~" in Response.Redirect stays to the application root.

Comment: thank you for replay..No no sorry for that mistake actually both the urls are same.. if i browse www.domain.com/Portals/client/default.aspx any page with capital P or any upper case letter in poRtals it is redirecting to 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: after redicting correctly also is i make any character Upper case letter in poRtals , it is redirecting to url www.domain.com/poRtals/client/default.aspx but 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: Is "client" the app root? I would check IIS log for errors and try to reboot the server. If nothing helps - copy your app to a new directory e.g. "portals2" and try to run it from here to see what happens. Looks like you have an extra configuration somewhere.

Comment: exactly client is my app root no error log written, now i made that  `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx",false); `now its working fine but i didnot get the issue

Comment: I think, it does not solve anything and you will get that problem again later on. It looks like somewhere in the code you are looking for "portals" in lower case and it leads to 404 if not found. I would still suggest to search for dependences to "portals" and try to rename (or add a new folder with other name) and see what happens.

Comment: no im sure, nowhere i used portals, because it is client folder where they deployed.